# linking error: undefined reference to icu_50::UnicodeString::UnicodeString()

Tags: linker-errors, static-linking, icu, unicode-string, gcc4.7

I am trying to compile my project where I've declared as class members some:

```
icu::UnicodeString label;
icu::UnicodeString tags;
icu::UnicodeString domain;
icu::UnicodeString data;
```

After having included (yes it is found)

```
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
```

In my CMakeLists.txt it searches, finds and links with: icuuc icudata (libicuuc, libicudata) as the output suggests prior to throwing the errors:

> -o icarus -rdynamic -lPocoNet -lPocoUtil -lPocoXML -licuuc -licudata

I have built and installed from source icu4c 50.1.2, and installed it under /usr/local/*
cmake finds the libraries properly, as my errors are from the linking phase:

> undefined reference to `icu_50::UnicodeString::UnicodeString()'
>   undefined reference to`icu_50::UnicodeString::~UnicodeString()'

I am using gcc-4.7.2 with -std=c++0x enabled on Debian Wheezy.
The exact same code did compile with gcc-4.3.2 with the same flags on Debian Squeeze last night!

I cannot for the life of me, figure out what I am doing wrong! Please help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears this was my fault when building ICU4C.
I am leaving a brief explanation as I have seen many google posts on this but no answers.
If you read carefully the documentation when configuring icu, it states that you should do certain things:

1) Define using namespace to false:

```
 #   ifndef U_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE
-#       define U_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE 1
+        // Set to 0 to force namespace declarations in ICU usage.
+#       define U_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE 0
```

2) When building on linux, I went for a non-shared, static library:

```
runConfigureICU Linux --enable-static --disable-shared
```

3) This is the important part that caused my errors:

*By default, ICU library entry point names have an ICU version suffix. Turn this off for a system-level installation, to enable upgrading ICU without breaking applications. For example:*

```
runConfigureICU Linux --disable-renaming
```

*The public header files from this configuration must be installed for applications to include and get the correct entry point names.*

I did do that on Squeeze, but not on Wheezy, thus causing all the linkage errors on a system-wide installation.
Lesson learned, hope it helps someone else.